# Синонимизировать [машинное-обучение] и [machine-learning]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Нужно синонимизировать

- [машинное-обучение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) (137 вопросов)
- [machine-learning](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) (8 вопросов)

Основная метка - [машинное-обучение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)